# TeamCity keeps using the same agent if it fails

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

My current TeamCity setup has several agents with pretty much the same configuration and all of them are also eligible for running the builds. However, I have noticed that TeamCity keeps scheduling runs on the same agent in a roll, even if the build fail. Actually, it happens only when it fails. Is this a known behaviour or a bug? Is there any way to change such configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Check your "Agent Requirements" in the build conf according to https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Agent+Requirements

Comment: I have 10 agents compatible agents. The page "Agent Requirements" only confirms that.

Comment: What type of build trigger do you have ? Schedule ?

Comment: No, they are triggered for pre-merge or post-merge